# client goes down before receiving the response from the server

Tags: spring-boot, rest, asynchronous, microservices

I have applications A and B, A sends a HTTP Request to B, while B processing and generating Response, A went down.

Is there any possible way to log this issue at application B??

It's a Spring Boot Application.

I tried to find any solution but didn't get any.

Answer (score 0):

If application A goes away during a rest request, there should be some kind of `IOException` thrown in application B which you should be able to catch/intercept with an `@ExceptionHandler`.

<s>I would suggest trying to simulate the failure of application A by using [wiremock](https://wiremock.org/), I found and example of how to do that on [medium](https://medium.com/@bubu.tripathy/simulate-network-failures-in-a-spring-boot-application-60e2ecb7daab).</s> (wiremock is as far as I can tell only for testing the client, and here we want to test the server side).

Ok, so it took a bit of time for me to actually reproduce your scenario (I did not get the exact CLOSE_CONNECTION_NOW, which I think will require lower level network programming to simulate but I got a org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException), with the following single class spring boot application which intercepts and logs the exception (I left out imports for brevity):

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@Slf4j
@ControllerAdvice
public class ClientTimeoutApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ClientTimeoutApplication.class, args);
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> streamContentAsFile() {
        StreamingResponseBody responseBody = response -> {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
                response.write((String.format("%4d\n", i)).getBytes());
                response.flush();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        };
        return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).body(responseBody);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(IOException.class)
    public void handle(IOException e) {
        log.warn("Caught IOException:", e);
    }
}
```

If you do `curl http://localhost:8080` and CTRL+C it while it is downloading or you can se the custom logging of the exception.

The example is based on spring boot 3.1.2, but should work similar on older versions), it uses `lombok` as the only dependency besides `spring-boot-starter-web`.

Comment: Yes It throws an IO Exception, but the problem  it is thrown internally  at some Abstract class of some library and handled there only. Any idea how I can catch it.                                                    o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Error state [CLOSE_CONNECTION_NOW] reported while processing request
java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Comment: It should be possible to somehow intercept the exception with a custom exception handler, but I could be wrong, If I get the time I will try to reproduce you example.

Comment: I tried multiple ways to intercept it but no luck , Finally decided to have a health check call before sending back the response, In case you get some time  to reproduce and intercept it let me know.

Comment: Could you post the full stacktrace of the exception in application B (redact/rename private classes if needed). I did try aborting the client request but so far I think it makes a clean shutdown, I think I need a hard kill of the client to provoke the server side exception.

Comment: Ok, I have updated my initial answer attempt to include an example.

Comment: I have reproduced this scenario in exactly same way, it seems to me you are getting this exception over here due to StreamingResponseBody, if you stop using it and try to send all data as a single response, you will not see this exception.

As you mentioned we might need some low level network Programming to handle this, or  have some buisness logic
like having response cached until next come if next one has same unique id raise alert sort of.

Comment: I was not able to produce an exception in the logs with a simple GET request that did not stream its response (even if the server thread was sleeping and the client was killed). But you mention that you do see an exception in your logs, so it must be possible in certain scenarios where it can happen. I think more details about your specific setup is needed to get any further.